# Complex htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here's the problem; Replaced a Magento site with my own.  I need to redirect something like:

```
http://example.com/store/index.php/figures/something/somethingelse.html?dest=products&prod_id=4625
```

To:

```
http://example.com/store/index.php?dest=products&prod_id=4625
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: That's not necessarily complex at all, except that you haven't shared anything regarding what URLs should *not* be redirected.

Comment: How do you mean?  Anything with the formula on top needs redirection to the one on the bottom.

Comment: So basically replace `/store/index.php/figures/something/somethingelse.html` with `/store/index.php` in URL?

Comment: Your comment to @anubhava's answer below about the "figures" token is what I meant; your question did not say anything about what parts were variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(store/index\.php)/[^/]+/.+$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: What if "figures" was variable?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. No change after clearing cache and trying different browser.

Comment: That s only possible if either there is a rule before it OR there is another .htaccess in your system. Are you sure this .htaccess is placed in root?

Comment: OK my bad, was another htaccess in there, I have consolidated them and everything is perfect!!!  Thank logical expression master!